# While re-sizing web page have the two sizes adjust first

Tags: css, html, resize

I have a HTML page with divs that are vertically placed in the center part of the page.
[image]
*Note: It only contains divs in the center and not the two sides.

My requirement is that when I re-size my page it should have the center divs unchanged while the two sides should get thinner and thinner until the center divs are the only things that are visible. Sounds complex? Please check the link below.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.TestMasterPage" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

        #header
        {
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
        margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:#303033;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }

        #menuBar1
        {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
     margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
       min-width:800px;
        min-height:2px;       
        }

         #menuBar2
        {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
       margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        min-height:20px;
        background-color:#F5F5F5;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;

        }

         #mainContentArea
        {
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#F5F5F5;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }

         #interfaceArea1
        {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
      margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:20px;
        background-color:#F5F5F5;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }

         #contentArea1
        {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
     margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#F5F5F5;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }

        #contentArea2
        {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#F5F5F5;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }

        #footer
        {
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:8.0em;
        margin-right:8.0em;
        min-width:800px;
        height:35px;
        background-color:#303033;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        }



      ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:0;


}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#303033;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#CCC;
}

    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="header">

    </div>    

    <div id="menuBar1">
   <ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Applications</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Webservice</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Android</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">.NET</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Other</a></li>

</ul>
    </div>

    <div id="menuBar2">

    </div>

     <div id="mainContentArea">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>

    <div id="interfaceArea1">

    </div>

    <div id="contentArea1">

    </div>

    <div id="contentArea2">

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add some (short, but working) example (some markup and css)? It would also help if you tell us what you've tried so far to get this effect, be specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: hey ya sure thing, just added the code for further reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content to stay in the middle, you should not set a `min-width` but either a fixed `width` or a `max-width`. Combine this with `auto` margins for left and right, which will tell the browser to center the content. For example this setup:

```
body {
    max-width: 800px; /* can also be "width" depending on your requirements */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

In the above example I applied it to the `body` element, but basically you can do this with any block element (in your case* one of the content divs).

There are a lot of other examples out there for this kind of layout. For example [ironmyers layouts](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/) has [this one-column fixed width layout](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/950_pixel_Layouts/layout/?id=7) you seem to be after.

---

* Note: you haven't exactly made it easy to phrase the answer in your context, because the code you provided isn't quite an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), with a lot of irrelevant markup.

Answer (score 1):

Look into CSS media queries and read up about responsive design.

You'll probably want to set a width on the center `divs` as well.

Comment: As you can see I have tried the min-width attribute.. but when you run this code it only applies the expected changes to one side, any idea.